# bootstrap-table display a json API

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) to display a json api data (http://apis.firsthelpfinancial.com/ords/fhfcoll/call_vol_overtime_by_colector/). However, nothing shows, anyone knows the reason? Thank you so much!

```
   <table data-toggle ="table"
           data-classes="table table-hover table-condensed"
           data-striped="true"
           data-url=""
           data-search="true"
           data-toolbar="#toolbar"
           data-search-align = "left"
           data-toolbar-align = "right" 
           data-height="500"
           data-pagination="true"
           data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]"
           data-show-export="true"
           data-show-refresh="true"
     >

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="items.period" data-sortable = "true" data-halign="center" data-align="left">Period</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: sorry, forget the data-url="http://apis.firsthelpfinancial.com/ords/fhfcoll/call_vol_overtime_by_colector/"

Comment: How are you calling the JSON? Are you getting getting any errors in your console? Check the network tab to see if the call you are making is successful or not.

Comment: @crazymatt Thank you for reply. I call JSON by setting:  data-url="http://apis.firsthelpfinancial.com/ords/fhfcoll/call_vol_overtime_by_colector/ "

Comment: @crazymatt  no errors (304)  in network